# How do I calculate date difference between rows with respect to a grouped index PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas

I have a repeated measured data set (many observations per person, one row per observation).

I need to calculate the date difference in number of days from a subjects first observation until their last. So for the following toy problem...

```
## toy problem
d = {'one' : Series(['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'], index = [0,1,2,3,4,5]),
 'two' : Series([1.1, 2.5, 3.3, 2.5, 3.3, 9.5], index = [0,1,2,3,4,5]),
 'date' : Series(['2014-01-01', '2014-01-07', '2014-01-14', '2014-02-01', '2014-02-07',    '2014-02-14'])}
df = DataFrame(d)

df["date_d"] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

You would get an output of 0, 7, 8, 0, 7, 8

Answer (score 0):

```
datediff = lambda x: (x - x.min())
transformed = df.groupby('one').date_d.transform(datediff)
df['days_since'] = transformed - date(1970, 1, 1)
```

did the trick